# Work remotely in a EU country for a non EU company

Tags: contract-law, germany

I am a German citizen permanently living in Germany. Is it legal to be employed by a company located in Mauritius and work 100% remotely without ever visiting Mauritius?

Comment: I am not knowledgeable of Mauritius law, but generally speaking what matters is that the employee be allowed to work in the country where he is performing the job. Since you are a German citizen performing 100% of your job in Germany, that seems completely legal regardless of whether you have ever been to Mauritius.

Comment: The question doesn't mention that, but the tax issues are very relevant. E.g. it may be that it counts as exporting services and taxes like VAT need to be applied; and the declaration of income is likely to have extra requirements if you're not working for an EU company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under German law, yes sure. As long as you keep to all regulations.

You have to declare your taxes. This is income, whether it comes from inside Germany or not and whether it is paid into a German bank account or foreign.

You have to have a health insurance and likely need to pay into the social security and pension funds. As your employer most likely does *not* do this for you as a German employer would be required to, you will need to pay *both* the employee *and* the employer's part yourself.

So yes, if you pay your taxes on it and have health and social security insurance, Germany does not care where the money comes from.

Now whether the company in Mauritius is legally allowed to hire and pay you under their law? I have no idea.

Please note that filling out all the right forms correctly is not for the faint of heart.  And finding out that you did it wrong only years later is painful and costly. Also calculate your costs before you do anything. Paying both parts for your health insurance for example can easily be up to 400€ a month *more* then a German employee at a German company, so run your numbers. You may be better off being officially self-employed or even incorporated. Just because it's legal, does not mean it's a good idea. Hire a professional to advise you on the economic and bureaucratic side of this.